# NSNumberFormatter leaks on NSCFNumber getObjectValue

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

I created a common method "isValidAmount" to check if the user inputs a correct amount in UITextField. This is working, but the problem is, I am getting leaks when the number is invalid. The leaked object is "NSCFNumber" and the responsible for that is "getObjectValue".  I don't know what else to do.  I already release the "formatter" below.  I even tried to release "number" below.  But still I keep on getting this leak.  Please help.

```
+ (BOOL) isValidAmount:(NSString *)amount {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:amount];
    [formatter release];
    if (!number) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, there is nothing wrong with that code.

Does it also leak on the device?  Can you post the exact backtrace of the allocation that is leaked?

Comment: Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFNumber   0x787c1c0 16 Foundation getObjectValue
NSCFNumber   0x787ada0 16 Foundation getObjectValue

Comment: i haven't got a license to run on the device yet... only using instruments... is the above the backtrace you need?

Comment: The simulators want work exactly like the device and there are a handful of bugs in both instrumentation and runtime in simulator.  If you can reproduce th issue with a relatively small example, please file a bug (as it looks like a bug).

Comment: thanks bbum, i will try to file this... i guess i leave it like this for now... or is there other way to do validation without using the numberFromString: method? honestly, i'd like to stick with this method if not only for that mysterious leak